# jooq: give an alias at a "is not null" field

Tags: jooq

How can I give an alias for a field where I am using `is not null`, for example

`create.select(SOMETABLE.ID.isNotNull()`

I can't use `.as(..)` after `isNotNull()`

Thanks

I am using an old version of jooq, 3.4.x.
I don't think it matters but I am using apache derby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DSL.field(Condition)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field(org.jooq.Condition)) to turn a `Condition` into a `Field<Boolean>`